# AttributeError: module ‘xgboost’ has no attribute ‘XGBRegressor’

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, spyder, xgboost

I am trying to run xgboost using spyder and python, but I keep getting this error:

**AttributeError: module ‘xgboost’ has no attribute ‘XGBRegressor’**

Here is the code:

```
import xgboost as xgb 

xgb.XGBRegressor(max_depth=3, learning_rate=0.1, n_estimators=100, silent=True, 
                 objective='reg:linear', gamma=0, min_child_weight=1, 
                 max_delta_step=0, subsample=1, colsample_bytree=1, 
                 seed=0, missing=None)
```

**Error is**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-33-d257a9a2a5d8>", line 1, in <module>
    xgb.XGBRegressor(max_depth=3, learning_rate=0.1, n_estimators=100, silent=True,

AttributeError: module 'xgboost' has no attribute 'XGBRegressor'
```

I have
Python 3.5.2 :: Anaconda 4.2.0 (x86_64)

How do I solve this?

Comment: If you put `print(dir(xgb))` after your import statement, what do you get?

Comment: print(dir(xgb)) 

['__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']

Comment: Problem for me was, the source code file had the same name as the lib file containing the regressor defintion: "xgboost.py". Renamed the file, fixed it.

Answer (score 6):

We probably have the same problem.

I solved it by telling Python explicitly where to find xgboost library.

The reason is that I have more than one scripts with the name xgboost.py. Python might have imported one of them mistakenly, so that it cannot find the definition of 'XGBRegressor'.

Here is the command I used:

```
export PYTHONPATH=PATH_TO_YOUR_setup.py_file
```

For me, PATH_TO_YOUR_setup.py_file is ~/xgboost/python-package

Answer (score 4):

Probably there are many files with the same name of `xgboost`.That is why python tries to load one of these instead of the original package file.

**Tip**
Check your working directory and see if there are any py files with the same name of `xgboost.py`.
If so, Change the name to something else.

Comment: yup, this was my problem

Comment: There was a file called xgboost.py. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Since your `dir` call is missing basically everything, my suspicion is that wherever you're starting your script from has an `xgboost` subfolder with an empty `__init__.py` in it that is being found first by your `import`.

Comment: I have checked the folder structure where my .py file is kept and it doesn't have any xgboost folder in it. Is there a way to check this or get the path from where xgboost is getting called from.

Comment: I am on a mac, i have done a folder search for xgboost on the entire disk and i can't see a folder named xgboost. Where are the python packages stored on the disk?

Comment: Was a bit of a shot in the dark. If you're using anaconda, it should drop packages in `[your anaconda install folder]/lib/python3.5/site-packages`

Answer (score 2):

For my case, I solve this problem pretty easily using

`from xgboost import XGBRegressor`

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem with Python 3.6.2 and Anaconda 1.6.8 on windows10 64bits (fall creator update)

To get it to work, here is what I did :

1/ Uninstall xgboost from within anaconda, in the chosen environement.

2/ Manually deleted the xgboost directory in C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3

3/ Downloaded xgboost from [This page](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#xgboost)

4/ From Anaconda, launch a command prompt from (from the environment you want xgboost into of course)

5/ CD to the directory you downloaded the whl file to and type : pip install xgboost‑0.6+20171121‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl  (or the exact name of the file you downloaded)

I did all these steps and xgboost worked properly

Comment: Does it work for windows too? The link you gave seems to only have `.whl` for windows.

Comment: I have used it only on w10, it works fine but I don't know for other OS

Answer (score 0):

I had to make sure to follow all the download instructions from the xgboost website. After installing and compiling, i forgot to run these. 
https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html#python-package-installation