# Python: xgboost can import but unable to use due to no attributes existing?

Tags: python, import, attributeerror, xgboost

The most similar question I found was here:

[AttributeError: module ‘xgboost’ has no attribute ‘XGBRegressor’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40005093/attributeerror-module-xgboost-has-no-attribute-xgbregressor)

However it had no solution. I used these instructions to install it:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/jfp/entry/Installing_XGBoost_For_Anaconda_on_Windows?lang=en

At first, it wouldn't import in Spyder as it was missing libstdc++-6.dll from mingw, so I copied it into the Anaconda3 folder with python.exe and it was able to import. However I am now unable to use any of the classes/attributes that are supposed to be in the package:

after an import with no errors:

```
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(X_train, label=y_train)
```

or

```
xgb.XGBClassifier()
```

returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-46-c2cc512a257d>", line 1, in <module>
    dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(X_train, label=y_train)

AttributeError: module 'xgboost' has no attribute 'DMatrix'
```

also

```
dir(xgboost)
```

returns

```
['__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']
```

and

```
help(xgboost)
```

returns

```
Help on package xgboost:

NAME
    xgboost

PACKAGE CONTENTS
    callback
    compat
    core
    libpath

FILE
    (built-in)
```

However I have a screenshot from a terminal opened earlier today where it returned this (I don't know what I could have changed):

[image]

Comment: Having the same issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46010755/xgboost-dmatrix. I ran help(xgboost) and found no contents. Thinking I wiped it out at some point. I think the best bet is to do the ole uninstall reinstall.