# xgboost cannot import attributes in ipython notebook

Tags: python, xgboost

I had installed xgboost and it was working fine both on my python terminal and on my ipython notebook. But suddenly I started getting problems on ipython notebook. 
When I type `xgb.DMatrix` I get `module 'xgboost' has no attribute 'DMatrix'` in ipython but on python terminal I get `<class 'xgboost.core.DMatrix'>`.Actually none of the attibutes are working on ipython.

I already tried deleting the xgboost folder and redownloading it but the problem persists.

I don't think that this is a duplicate question as I have mentioned that :

a. Its working fine in python terminal but not in ipython notebook

b. The problem was still not resolved for the OP([AttributeError: module ‘xgboost’ has no attribute ‘XGBRegressor’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40005093/attributeerror-module-xgboost-has-no-attribute-xgbregressor))

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40005093/attributeerror-module-xgboost-has-no-attribute-xgbregressor

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AttributeError: module ‘xgboost’ has no attribute ‘XGBRegressor’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40005093/attributeerror-module-xgboost-has-no-attribute-xgbregressor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by deleting xgboost folder and reinstalling it according to this [post](https://isaacchanghau.github.io/2017/06/20/Install-XGBoost-on-Mac-OS-X/)