# AttributeError: 'XGBClassifier' object has no attribute 'save_raw'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

I keep getting the error mentioned in the title whenever I try to compile my file. I'm basically using this file https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/python-package/xgboost/training.py

and the error happens on line 38 at save_raw

I've tried reinstalling different versions of xgboost with both pip and git clone, nothing seems to work. Can someone help me?

I am using the latest version of scikit, python and xgboost.

```
if xgb_model is not None:
    if not isinstance(xgb_model, STRING_TYPES):
        xgb_model = xgb_model.save_raw() //Error here
    bst = Booster(params, [dtrain] + [d[0] for d in evals], model_file=xgb_model)
```

nboost = len(bst.get_dump())

Comment: Try it without assigning it, leave out the `xgb_model = ` and just run `xgb_model.save_raw('filename')` and see if that works for you

Comment: I used this advice https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40005093/attributeerror-module-xgboost-has-no-attribute-xgbregressor of export PYTHONPATH=PATH_TO_YOUR_setup.py_file,

but now i get a new error AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'dtypes'

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced with save in `**XGBRegressor**`
I think it is same with `**XGBClassifier**`.

I can working with `**save_model**` and `**load_model**` but some objects will not be saved or loaded.

```
def load_model(self, fname):
    """
    Load the model from a file.

    The model is loaded from an XGBoost internal binary format which is universal among the various XGBoost interfaces. Auxiliary attributes of the Python Booster object (such as feature names) will not be loaded. 
    Label encodings (text labels to numeric labels) will be also lost.
    **If you are using only the Python interface, we recommend pickling the model object for best results.**
```

So another solutions is considered
with me, **pickle** package works well

```
import pickle
pickle.dump(model, open("boston_earlyStopping.dat", "wb"))
new_model = pickle.load(open("boston_earlyStopping.dat", "rb"))
new_model.best_ntree_limit
```

> 99

Comment: instead of a printscreen you should paste the code as text